# Structure of a conditional statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

is it possible to have a conditional statement in Javascript that looks like the following?

```
if (condition === value || value) {}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it? But I also imagine that you probably think this syntax means a different thing than what it actually means

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what you want.

```
if (condition === value || value) {
    //
}
```

As it looks like, you check a value with another [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, like `0`, `undefined`, `false`, `null` **or** (by using a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())) with the [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value itselft.

For the first condition, any check with a truthy value do not make sense.

Comment: when there are 2 or more possible values passed to a method and you wanted to check on each one, this short hand way helps. I just tried it and it works fine.
Thanks for your and other peoples feedback

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve it by using the below code:

```
if((condition === value) || (condition === value)){ 
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can not used the specified format if (condition === value || value) {}

Every Comparison Operators should be separated with valid condition and the condition have to return a boolean value.

example
if (expression) {}